# Como Pegar resultados dentro do loop e agrupando em uma variavel fora dele

Tags: php

Como Pegar resultados dentro do loop e agrupando em uma variavel fora dele
Exemplo:

```
$sql55 = "SELECT * FROM finan WHERE MONTH(data_fechamento)= '02' ";
$resultado55 = mysql_query($sql55) or die( mysql_error());
while ($row55 = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado55)) {
echo '<br>';
echo $vencimento2 =  $row55['vencimento'];
//  retorno echo  2017-02-02
                  2017-02-04
                  2017-02-05
                  2017-02-03
}

// queria pegar esse mesmo daros em uma variaval fora do while
echo $juntandoresultados; // exmplo

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql55 = "SELECT * FROM finan WHERE MONTH(data_fechamento)= '02' ";
$resultado55 = mysql_query($sql55) or die( mysql_error());
$juntandoresultados="";
while ($row55 = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado55)) {

$juntandoresultados .= "<br>".$row55['vencimento'];

}
echo $juntandoresultados;
```

Comment: Pra sua resposta ficar perfeita só tá faltando pôr $juntandoresultados=""; antes do while. Pois do jeito que está, ao passar a primeira vez no while dará um erro de que a varíavel $juntandoresultados  não existe.

Comment: beleza, já coloquei

Comment: Marque a resposta como escolhida :)

Answer (score 1):

Salvar dentro de um array ajudaria?

```
$dados = array();

$sql55 = "SELECT * FROM finan WHERE MONTH(data_fechamento)= '02' ";
$resultado55 = mysql_query($sql55) or die( mysql_error());
while ($row55 = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado55)) {
  array_push($dados,$row55['vencimento']);
}

print_r($dados);
```

----------------------ou assim ------

```
$dados = "";

$sql55 = "SELECT * FROM finan WHERE MONTH(data_fechamento)= '02' ";
$resultado55 = mysql_query($sql55) or die( mysql_error());
while ($row55 = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado55)) {
  $dados .= $row55['vencimento']." ";
}

echo $dados ;
```

Comment: Acredito que sua segunda opção resolve o problema da maneira que ele quer. Só que ao invés de espacinho no final ele está concatenando com <br> na frente.